# My div element is pushed to the left when span is toggled

Tags: css

Difficult to explain so I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p4v0rmns/)...

As you can see when you press the button and toggle the `span` or notification the `div` or icon shifts to the left...

Is there any way in CSS to make the icon stay in place? I'm sure it's something simple that I'm overlooking or overthinking.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you position your notification icon absolutely it won't take up any space.

Just change the positioning on .todoListNotification to absolute and change left to something like 15px.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something simple.